# In common-lisp is there a way to code an 'apply' equivalent for macros?

Tags: macros, common-lisp

I have a macro: `mac1(&rest args)` that accepts any number of arguments

Since I cannot use `apply` with a macro, and since I have no control on the macro's implementation,  how can I make a function `fun1 (lst)` that given a list, calls the macro with the expanded list?

**UPDATE**: I though the question was adequate but it seems better to state my real case:

Postmodern provides the query macro:

```
macro: query (query &rest args/format)
```

For example you call it like this:

`(query 
    "select * from example where col1 = $1::integer and col2 = $2::date" 
    123 
    "2017-01-01"
    :str-alists)`

Ok, now imagine that at runtime I am passed this list:

```
'((:query "select * from table1 where c1 = $1 and c2 = $2 and c3 = $3"
   :params (1 "2017-01-01" 3) :return :str-alists

  (:query "select * from tab2 where c3 = $1"
   :params ("somevalue") :return :lists)
   .
   .
   .
  ))
```

And I have to do the queries. I need to define a function that will take such a list as argument and do the queries. But since query is a macro I have the following problem: I need somewhere to evaluate the lists in order to pass them to the macro. Currently I am doing this (idea taken from @melpomene comments) :

```
(defun macro-apply(q p ret)
  (eval (macroexpand `(query ,q ,@p ,ret))))
```

So the function becomes:

```
(defun exec-queries (lst)
    (mapc 
       (lambda(x) (macro-apply 
                      (getf x :query) 
                      (getf x :params) 
                      (getf x :return))
       lst))
```

Is there a better way, or something obvious that I am missing?

Comment: `(macroexpand \`(mac1 ,@lst))`?

Comment: How would I implement that into a function so that I can pass a list variable that can be evaluated at some point?

Comment: Why are you repeating your question? Do you just want me to copy/paste my comment?

Comment: but you didnt post a function. I really dont understand how to make a function from this. Do you mean something like `(defun macro-apply(lst) (macroexpand \`(mac1 ,@lst)))` . Woudln't I need to eval its return value since its return value is code?. Sorry If I am missing something obvious.

Comment: You said you wanted to call the macro. You didn't say anything about doing something with the return value. And yes, the return value is code (= a list that represents code). If you're thinking about eval'ing it at runtime, why is this thing even a macro in the first place and not a function?

Comment: because it is a macro from an external library and the library doesn't provide a function. Normaly, you call the macro in your functions and pass it directly its arguments. But in my case, at runtime, I am repeatedly given some list of arguments (that I dont know beforehand and that vary in length) and I am requested to call the macro with those arguments.

Comment: @melpomene I have updated my question to better illustrate.

Comment: Btw., you don't need to call MACROEXPAND. EVAL does that anyway.

Comment: Generally it is like that. Note that EVAL might not compile things and use an Interpreter to run that. Also repeated queries need to be parsed/... each time they will be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can also use COMPILE or even COMPILE-FILE + LOAD to deal with that.

For example in some situations it might be useful to output the query forms in some format and some embedding into a file. You can then compile the file and load the code - either to execute on load or later.

Primitive version:

1. generate a file, put an `IN-PACKAGE` form into it and dump one or more query forms into it.
2. compile the file with `COMPILE-FILE`
3. handle for errors...
4. loading the file then executes the queries

If you want to do something with the results, you have to put some more code for that into the file...

This example would require that the function `compile-file` and the necessary library/macro code is available at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your actual problem, note that the macro uses a low-level package, *cl-postgres*, to implement the queries using functions (see http://quickdocs.org/postmodern/api#system-cl-postgres). The macro is only syntactic sugar for the underlying API. Let's see how the macro is expanded with a parameterized query:

```
CL-USER> (macroexpand
           '(postmodern:query 
               "select * from table where col1=$1:integer" 
               20))

(PROGN
 (CL-POSTGRES:PREPARE-QUERY POSTMODERN:*DATABASE* ""
                            "select * from table where col1=$1:integer")
 (CL-POSTGRES:EXEC-PREPARED POSTMODERN:*DATABASE* "" (LIST 20)
                            'CL-POSTGRES:LIST-ROW-READER))
```

As usual with SQL, you first defined *prepared* statements, to avoid injection attacks. If you reuse the same queries often, it is more efficient to prepare them only once (see `defprepared`). Then, you execute the queries.

When you also specify the result type (last keyword argument from the query), the macro calls the unexported `reader-for-format` function, to know which callback function to use for each row.

```
(macroexpand
 '(postmodern:query "select * from table where col1=$1:integer"
   20
   :str-alist))
(MULTIPLE-VALUE-CALL
    #'(LAMBDA
          (&OPTIONAL (POSTMODERN::ROWS) (POSTMODERN::AFFECTED) &REST #:G843)
        (DECLARE (IGNORE #:G843))
        (IF POSTMODERN::AFFECTED
            (VALUES (CAR POSTMODERN::ROWS) POSTMODERN::AFFECTED)
            (CAR POSTMODERN::ROWS)))
  (PROGN
   (CL-POSTGRES:PREPARE-QUERY POSTMODERN:*DATABASE* ""
                              "select * from table where col1=$1:integer")
   (CL-POSTGRES:EXEC-PREPARED POSTMODERN:*DATABASE* "" (LIST 20)
                              'CL-POSTGRES:ALIST-ROW-READER)))
T
```

Since the macro already does all the job for you, you can effectively wrap your queries in new forms and evaluate them, provided you don't evaluate arbitrary Lisp forms (prepared statements guard you against SQL injections, but EVAL opens up another attack vector; check your inputs).

Or, try to see how to use the building blocks of the query to produce your own query interpreter. At first glance, it seems like some sort of "inner platform effect" to get arbitrary queries and process them, but maybe you have a good use case for this.

Comment: It sounds like that but it isnt. I still will write the queries. I just dont want to create an api endpoint and front end input fields specifically for every report someone might think of.

Comment: @Paralife Is this for expert users who write SQL queries? (just by curiosity)

Comment: No its for me. I will be writing the queries. I get a lot of requests for custom queries to be available in a web app, and i have to mess with a lot of boilerplate in the front end to publish a component or a page for the query (input fields, api endpoints etc). Now I will create a front end template page/component for a generic report and I will write the query and parameter types in a lisp file as a plist. I will send the params to the client, it will render the input fields, return the parameter values and I will feed them along with the query text into my function this question is about.

Comment: I know i could write minimal code to call directly the query macro for each report, but it is another hassle and the reports sometimes are ephimeral. Now I will have a directory with files each containing the report definition in a plist. If I remove the file, the report is removed. And if I add a file, a report  is "magically" available in the users front end, without doing anything else.

Comment: @Paralife Thanks for the explanation